# How to configure flushMode property of OpenSessionInViewInterceptor of spring 3.1.4

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

As I am planning to update from "hibernate3" to "hibernate4" & "spring 3.0.5" to "spring 3.1.4".

I have configured **OpenSessionInViewInterceptor** in spring 3.0.5 so want to configure same in 3.1.4.

But I am  not able to configure `flushMode` in `OpenSessionInViewInterceptor` of Spring 3.1.4;

My Previous setting for **spring 3.0.5** was:

```
<bean name="openSessionInViewInterceptor"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewInterceptor">
      <property name="sessionFactory">
             <ref bean="sessionFactory" />
      </property>
      <property name="flushMode">
             <bean
                   id="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.FLUSH_NEVER"
                   class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.FieldRetrievingFactoryBean" />
      </property>
</bean>
```

Now tried to configure same for spring 3.1.4 as below:

```
<bean name="openSessionInViewInterceptor"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewInterceptor">
    <property name="sessionFactory">
        <ref bean="sessionFactory" />
    </property>
    <property name="flushMode">
        <bean
            id="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.FLUSH_NEVER"
            class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.FieldRetrievingFactoryBean" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

then it throws below exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'flushMode' of bean class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewInterceptor]: Bean property 'flushMode' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
```

And there is no similar class found in alternate to `org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor` in spring 3.1.4

So my question is how to set flushMode property of OpenSessionInViewInterceptor of spring 3.1.4 ?

Answer (score 0):

It [looks](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate4/support/OpenSessionInViewInterceptor.html) like a mess, with unbound links to property accessors. I'd guess that a copy-paste job was done without much thinking about cleaning things up given the different inheritance hierarchies. I hate it when that happens…

Can you use the Hibernate 3 version instead? Yes, it really does appear to be there; here's the link: [`org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewInterceptor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/support/OpenSessionInViewInterceptor.html)

Longer term, look more carefully whether the Hibernate 4 code does what you want without specifying the flag at all. Unfortunately, you'll have to ignore the documentation (at least for now) and study [the source](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-orm/3.1.4.RELEASE/org/springframework/orm/hibernate4/support/OpenSessionInViewInterceptor.java/) itself.

Comment: Ya i know its just a copy-paste and there is no property accessors in OpenSessionInViewInterceptor of spring 3.1.4, thats why  I ask some way to do that.

Actually I want to integrate Hibernate Search in my Application, that's why move to hibernate 4 & spring 3.1.4.

Can we use `org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewInterceptor` with all settings 4 version. as when i tried to do that below exception came:

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.SessionFactory.openSession()Lorg/hibernate/classic/Session;`